# C++ leaks in case of exception even by using smart pointers

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, smart-pointers

I am new to the smart pointers world. I've done my reading and all of them stated that smart pointers will avoid leaking memory even when the program will exit after encountering an exception.

I wrote down a simple program to try this out, but [Valgrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) is telling me my program is leaking memory (three allocs and only one free).

This is the source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto_ptr<int> ptr_int(new int(5));

    throw std::bad_alloc();

    cout << *ptr_int;
}
```

And this Valgrind report:

```
==27862== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27862== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27862== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27862== Command: ./smart_pointers
==27862== Parent PID: 5388
==27862==
==27862==
==27862== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27862==     in use at exit: 104 bytes in 2 blocks
==27862==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 1 frees, 120 bytes allocated
==27862==
==27862== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2
==27862==    at 0x4026351: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:255)
==27862==    by 0x804878A: main (smart_pointers.cpp:8)
==27862==
==27862== 100 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2 of 2
==27862==    at 0x4025BD3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==27862==    by 0x40E861A: __cxa_allocate_exception (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14)
==27862==    by 0x80487AE: main (smart_pointers.cpp:10)
==27862==
==27862== LEAK SUMMARY:
==27862==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27862==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27862==      possibly lost: 100 bytes in 1 blocks
==27862==    still reachable: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==27862==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27862==
==27862== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27862== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 19 from 8)
```

Does using smart pointers guarantee the allocated resources will be destroyed even if an exception shows up?

Comment: You haven't caught the exception at all, So it ends up calling `terminate()` whose default behavior is to call `abort()`. What happens if you catch the exception?

Comment: If you're using a modern OS, the OS will reclaim any memory used by the program when it exits so you shouldn't worry about leaking memory per se. Of course, it's a different situation if you are using resources that you explicitly need to cleanup yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When [`std::terminate()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/termination.html) is called (as is the case for an uncaught exception), normal cleanup is not run (at least for the stack-frame of `main()`), and as such the memory you've allocated in that stack frame leaks, even though it's supposedly managed by a smart-pointer. When you're catching the `std::bad_alloc` in `main()`, and return normally, the smart-pointer will do it's duty.

Comment: Change that sentence to "smart pointers will avoid memory leak even in the case of _handled_ execptions". You're not handling the exception.

Comment: moving the code into foo() will not help if you do not catch the exception.  If you do not catch an exception (anywhere) then your application will terminate and destructors will not be called (what would be the point - the OS would reclaim all the memory in this case automatically).   use this: try {
  foo();
 } catch(std::bad_alloc ex)
 {

 }
then you should see the memory properly deallocated

Comment: I don't know about C++11, but originally, in C++ it was up to the implementation whether destructors are called on an unhandled exception. As of the point: Some destructors do more than reclaim memory (e.g. cleanly shut down server connections, delete temporary files, …). Therefore one could argue that it makes sense to call destructors even in this case. However, given that it is trivial to add a catch-all to `main` and not unwinding the stack can help with debugging, it was not mandated. I don't know whether there's any implementation which does unwind the stack for uncaught exceptions.

Answer (score 13):

If an exception is not handled, then it's implementation-defined whether the stack will be unwound before calling `std::terminate`.

If you handle the exception, then the smart pointer will work as expected.

Reference:

C++11 15.5.1 The `std::terminate()` function

> 1 In some situations exception handling must be abandoned for less subtle error handling techniques. These situations are:
>
> ........
>
> — when the exception handling mechanism cannot find a handler for a thrown exception , or
>
> ........
>
> 2 In such cases `std::terminate()` is called. **In the situation where no matching handler is found, it is implementation-defined whether or not the stack is unwound before `std::terminate()` is called**.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the Standard Reference, hope you don't mind it.

Answer (score 2):

If the exception is not caught, then the stack unwinding is implementation specific. Therefore in your case, it does not release the memory.

Also, auto_ptr is no longer recommended.

Use std::unique_ptr :

```
unique_ptr<int> ptr_int(new int(5));
```

Comment: To leave the main() clean I Moved the code into foo() But still the same issue. I think if the exceptions are not managed then smart pointers are for no help. However all the reading Iv done they stated "smart pointers will avoid memory leaks even in the case of execptions"

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

void foo()
{
 auto_ptr<int> ptr_int(new int(5));

 throw std::bad_alloc();

 cout << *ptr_int;
}

int main()
{
 foo();

 cout << "END";
}

Comment: About the reading : an exception will terminate your process and then all the memory will get released anyway. You should be worried about an uncaught exception more than a resource leak.


`#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int func()
{
 unique_ptr<int> ptr_int(new int(5));

 throw std::bad_alloc();

 cout << *ptr_int;

 return 0;
}


int main()
{
 try
 {
  func();
 }
 catch (...)
 {
  cout << "in catch all ..." << endl;
 }
 
}`

The above code releases the memory without any problem.