# Thrown exceptions being leaked in C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm fooling around a bit with C++, and as part of that have a piece of "restartable" code. To wit:

```
class handler {
public:
    virtual ~handler() {}
    virtual response handle(request &req) = 0;
};

response dispatch(request &req, handler &hnd) {
    try {
        return(hnd.handle(req));
    } catch(handler &rep) {
        return(dispatch(req, rep));
    }
}
```

Then, in another part of the code:

```
static response serve(request &req) {
    throw(resp::message("Merdel", {"Test"}));
}
```

Where `resp::message` is a subclass of `handler`.

This appears to work fine, but when I run it an Valgrind, it tells me this leaks memory:

```
==2609== 352 bytes in 11 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 12 of 16
==2609==    at 0x4C270FE: memalign (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2609==    by 0x4010BEF: tls_get_addr_tail (dl-tls.c:529)
==2609==    by 0x401110F: __tls_get_addr (dl-tls.c:767)
==2609==    by 0x668FC9B: __cxa_get_globals (eh_globals.cc:63)
==2609==    by 0x668F5EE: __cxa_allocate_exception (eh_alloc.cc:132)
==2609==    by 0x61DDA5E: serve(arw::request&) (arwtest.ashc:7)
==2609==    by 0x640E18B: arw::funhandler::handle(arw::request&) (arw.cpp:95)
==2609==    by 0x640E1C5: arw::dispatch(arw::request&, arw::handler&) (arw.cpp:100)
==2609==    by 0x640E487: arw::dispatch(ashd::request const&, arw::handler&) (arw.cpp:119)
==2609==    by 0x61DDBA7: _htstart (arwtest.ashc:11)
==2609==    by 0x403CCD: servehtstart (request.c:228)
==2609==    by 0x4040C5: servereq (request.c:303)
```

`serve(arw::request&) (arwtest.ashc:7)` is the `serve` function listed above.

Why does this leak memory? It is my understanding that the C++ runtime should free these exceptions for me automatically (and it's not like I have any ability to free them manually anyway, right?), so what could cause it not to?

I did find [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161401/leak-in-exception-code-c) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091082/c-leaks-in-case-of-exception-even-by-using-smart-pointers) previous questions on a similar theme, but they don't seem to be applicable here as they only treat a single leaked exception under exceptional circumstances, while this code leaks an exception per request (do note that 11 individual blocks are leaked; this is because I ran this test function 11 times during this test).

**EDIT**: I don't know if it's relevant or not, but it may be worth noting that `servehtstart` and `servereq` in the backtrace are functions in a pure-C program. `_htstart` and above are C++ code from a shared object that is `dlopen()`ed. It may also be relevant that it is only the `dlopen` of this shared object that at all brings `libstdc++` into the process.

Comment: How is your program ending ?

Comment: @quantdev: This particular code runs in a separate thread that terminates after `servereq` returns. In this example, one of these exceptions are thrown per thread. The program as a whole ends because I send it `SIGTERM`, which it catches and exits the main-loop in the thread running it. Also, see the edit to the question.

Comment: It's thread local storage that's not getting cleaned up. This is probably fine.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It doesn't seem fine if it's leaking for every thread I create. How do I make sure that the TLS does get cleaned up?

Comment: @Dolda2000 Check the functions shown in the stack and see when/how they allocate TLS and when/how they clean it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, this is a bug in certain versions of glibc, including the version currently in Debian Stable (namely, 2.13), but which has been since fixed. When running this same program on a Debian Testing setup (which uses glibc 2.19), the memory leak does not occur.

Apparently, glibc 2.13 does not properly clean up thread-local memory that is introduced by `dlopen()`'ed objects. It occurs here because `libstdc++` was only loaded as a consequence of the `dlopen()`. The issue is previously described in these two bug reports:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39366
- https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12650

The glibc commit which fixed the issue was [e6c61494](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/commitdiff/e6c61494125126d2ba77e5d99f83887a2ed49783).

Thanks @quantdev, @DavidSchwartz. Your comments made me realize what to look for.